# How to enable custom gcc parameters in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I needed to pass in "-std=c++0x" for g++ , in Qt Creator. I placed a variable in Build Environment:
[image]

But i still receive the warning:

> warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x to your .pro file.